# OAuth credential management

Tags: java, oauth, api-design

I am new to API development and iI encountered a situation that made me question some of the practices in API development.
The context is as follow, I have a web application where users can register client-id that they can use to consume different API later on.
When creating a client-id, the credentials are created through the backend app that communicates with the authorization server to store it.
but we provide the user the secret so he can generate the token later on.
I was wondering would it be ok to store the secret in a collection (map for example) in one of the backend classes, for an unknown amount of time and then retrieve it from the collection when the user asks for the secret.

I feel like, this should be avoided as the secret should not be stored in the backend application?